# Replace \" with "" in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

The data I am querying on contains `\"`, and I need to be able to convert it to `""` instead in the `SELECT` statement.

I tried using the following:
`SELECT REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'\"','""')` but that gives the following error: `` unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' ``

What is the appropriate query to replace `\"` with `""`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this expression `SELECT REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'\\\\\"','\"\"')`

Comment: That does not work. I did try ```SELECT REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'\\\"','\"\"')```, but that did not work either.

Comment: my bad, I used regex for Java strings. well, in case of SQL, for instance MySQL query works well with that regex you mentioned in your comment (three backslashes on the left side). seems that Spark's SQL needs the other one. try playing with number of backslashes more

Comment: Yup. This works with Java, which is where I solved the problem eventually.